# How should I write this in Swift?

Tags: swift

Let's say that I create a protocol like this:

```
protocol A {
 associatedtype T
 func computeSomething(with:T) -> Double
}
```

In my generic typed class, I would like to do something like this:

```
class B<U> {
 var doSomething:A<U>
}
```

This thing is that this generates an error, but I would like to accept any type that would support computeSomething on my type `U` but I don't know at all how to do that?

### Edit for clarity

Basically if A was a generic struct or class, that would be possible, but what if no default implementation (provided by class or struct) makes sense here and the only thing I want is to ensure that the type does what I want?

### Edit #2 (with concrete example)

I wanted to simplify my question which makes it pretty hard to understand so here is a still simplified and fictional problem that probably matches better the issue I am encountering:

I am writing a generic class that processes its generic type `T`:

```
class Process<T> { ... }
```

The class `Process` itself includes code that processes `T`, but in order for this code to work, it needs `T` to conform to some protocols, for instance:

```
protocol A {
    func mixWith(other:A) -> A
}

protocol B {
    var isFoo:Bool { get set }
}
```

So my first approach was to simply require `T` to conform to those protocols:

```
class Process<T:<A,B>> { ... }
```

This looks like the simplest approach and probably is in many cases, but in my case I think that this actually is problematic, for this reason:

First, I may need to process the same type in many different ways, and changing a way a type is being processed often requires changing the actual implementation of protocols `A` and `B` for instance in this case, `fooProcess` and `barProcess` are both of type `Process` with generic type `MyType`:

```
let fooProcess = Process<MyType>()
let barProcess = Process<MyType>()
```

But I want `fooProcess` and `barProcess` to do different operations which in many cases would require to change the implementation of the `A` and `B` protocols of my `MyType` type and that's simply not possible.

So my first idea was to simply require some closures and variables to be defined so that I wouldn't need protocols anymore and would define the way data is being processed only in my `Process` class, a little bit like this:

```
class Process<T> {
//
var mix:(_ lhs:T, _ rhs:T)->(T)
var isFoo:(_ a:T)->(Bool) 
...
}
```

There all of the processing would be directly implemented in my `Processing` class, again this would have looked like the right solution but now comes another issue, which led me to my associated type approach: it turns out that in many cases, the user of my `Process` class would want to get some default behaviour implemented by my framework, for instance, I could automatically implement protocol `A` and `B` for them as long as their class conformed to protocol `X`, here is how it did it:

```
protocol X:A,B {
...
}

extension protocol X {
   // Here was my default implementation of A and B, which enabled my user to directly get A and B implemented as long as their type conformed to X
}
```

By using this method, I would let my user directly choose what they wanted to implement themselves, by conforming to protocol `X` they would only need to write a little bit of code and let my framework to all of the rest by itself, and if they wanted to implement themselves A or B they still could.

**So if I am right, there is no way to do such a thing with my closures implementation.**

So for this reason, I thought that an associated type protocol would be a good solution because here I could let my users easily get some default behaviour or write their own, so now we are getting back to my original question:

```
protocol AProcessing {
    associatedtype U
    func mix(_ lhs:U, _ rhs:U) -> U 
}

protocol BProcessing {
   associatedtype U
   func isFoo(_ a:U) -> Bool
}
```

And then do something like that:

```
class Process<T> {
var aProcessor:AProcessing<T>
var bProcessor:BProcessing<T>
}
```

Here the advantage compared to closures is that I could write a special class conforming to AProcessing that could provide default implementation, this way:

```
class AutomaticAProcessing<T:X>:AProcessing { ... }
```

That would have enabled my users to so something like that:

```
var processData = Process<SomeType>()
processData.aProcessor = AutomaticAProcessing<SomeType>()
processData.bProcessor = TheirOwnImplemtation
```

Not only is this not possible in Swift, but it also feels like I am using too many "hacks" to get things done and there should be an easier language feature to do that, unfortunately I don't know what I should use.

Comment: I *think* you should write it as `class B<U> {
    var doSomething<U:A>
}` and you'll be fine

Comment: @Honey It doesn't compile either ! Looks like `<U:A>` isn't valid.

Comment: this question is **too long**, @TrevörAnneDenise.  I would encourage you to delete it, and make a new question, limit to 15 words.  If you can't ask it in 15 words, it's not a question.

Comment: This really looks like you've sliced the problem along the wrong axis. The statement "But I want fooProcess and barProcess to do different operations which in many cases would require to change the implementation of the A and B protocols of my MyType" screams "treating protocols as bags of syntax." (https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/) I would reconsider `Process` entirely, and likely compose in a different direction, probably with higher-order functions (i.e. functions that create and return other functions). That's generally a more powerful way to compose a process.

Comment: @Napier actually my Process class has nothing to do with an actual process, it's just called this way because it processes data

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, because the generic type of the protocol is specified in the class that implements it.

You could write something like this:

```
class B<U, P: A> where P.T == U {
    var someVar: P?
}
```

But then you would need to specify a second parameter with the specific class. For example:

```
class C: A {
    typealias T = String

    func computeSomething(with: String) -> Double {
        return 0.0
    }
}

let b = B<String, C>()
let c = b.someVar
```

But it can't return a protocol with specific type in its `associatedtype`

Comment: There actually isn't any need for a second generic placeholder. Just have `<P : A>`, and make a `typealias` inside the class of `typealias U = P.T`.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to start with an empty generic struct, and then extend it on types where it makes sense:

```
struct A<T> {}

extension A where T: Base {
  func computeSomething(with: T) -> Double {
    return 1
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
protocol Base {}

class B<U: Base> {
  let doSomething = A<U>()

  func foo(x: U) -> Double {
    return doSomething.computeSomething(with: x)
  }
}

class Z : Base {}

let x = B<Z>()
let y = x.foo(x: Z())
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

To EDIT #2:

Remove associated types, and it should be workable:

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {}

protocol AProcessing {
  func mix(_ lhs: A, _ rhs: A) -> A
}

protocol BProcessing {
  func isFoo(_ a: B) -> Bool
}
```

Then, your processor:

```
class Process<T: A & B> {
  var aProcessor: AProcessing!
  var bProcessor: BProcessing!

  func foo(_ a: T) -> Bool {
    let x = aProcessor.mix(a, a)
    guard let b = x as? B else { return false }
    return bProcessor.isFoo(b)
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
struct AutomaticAProcessing : AProcessing {
  func mix(_ lhs: A, _ rhs: A) -> A { return lhs }
}


struct TheirOwnImplemtation : BProcessing {
  func isFoo(_ a: B) -> Bool { return false }
}


struct SomeType : A, B {}

var processData = Process<SomeType>()
processData.aProcessor = AutomaticAProcessing()
processData.bProcessor = TheirOwnImplemtation()

let x = SomeType()
let y = processData.foo(x)
print(y)
```